# how to view list item in tibble

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

The `starwars` data set in `tidyverse`.

I want to view the name of Luke's first starship.

[image]

What's the notation I need to use to access it? (I.e., what can I enter at the command prompt to get the answer?)

(And to be more generic, how would I access **any** list item?)

I've gotten as far as this so far:

```
starwars %>% select(name, starships) %>% filter(name == "Luke Skywalker")
```

---

Update: the answer that worked:

```
starwars %>% select(name, starships) %>% filter(name == "Luke Skywalker") %>% pull(starships) %>% .[[1]] %>% .[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several other methods to do it in pipeline

```
starwars %>% select(name, starships) %>% filter(name == "Luke Skywalker") %>% str
tibble[,2] [1 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ name     : chr "Luke Skywalker"
 $ starships:List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "X-wing" "Imperial shuttle"
```

OR

```
starwars %>% select(name, starships) %>% filter(name == "Luke Skywalker") %>% as.data.frame()
            name                starships
1 Luke Skywalker X-wing, Imperial shuttle
```

Answer (score 1):

`starwars$starships[[1]]` would return the the 1st vector.

```
starwars$starships[[1]]
#[1] "X-wing"           "Imperial shuttle"
```

You can subset further -

```
starwars$starships[[1]][1]
#[1] "X-wing"
```

`dplyr` way -

```
library(dplyr)

starwars %>% select(starships) %>% pull(starships) %>% .[[1]]
```